# How to use loading.tsx in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a simple function to handFormData on `OnboardingForm.tsx` component.

```
  async function handleFormData(formData: FormData) {
    const result = await createUserFromForm(
      formData,
      clerkUserId as string,
      emailAddress as string
    )

    if (result) {
      await setUserDataAtClerk(
        clerkUserId as string,
        formData.get('firstName') as string,
        formData.get('lastName') as string
      )
      redirect('/dashboard')
    } else {
      console.error('User could not be created from form data')
    }
  }
```

I call this function from my form `<form action={handleFormData} >`

I also have a simple `loading.tsx` file placed in `/app/loading.tsx` which returns a `<h2>LOADING...</>`

Whenever I press Submit button on the form, `loading.tsx` file doesn't display the LOADING text. It just executes the `handleFormData` function and redirects to `/dashboard`

Is it because `handleFormData` is an async function? If thats the case, how can I display the `loading.tsx` while the form is processing?

Thank you.

Comment: do we need "use server" string inside your loading function ? I just read the docs and thought you need it though. I think we need it to define that is a server component. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions

Comment: Yes you need that, createUserFromForm and setUserDataAtClerk which handles the formData has the 'use server' in them which is on a seperate file /lib/actions.ts. This code works, the only thing that does work is not showing loading.tsx

Comment: hmm. i just rechecked the doc. you called `action={handleFormData}` so I think "use server" should be inside handleFormData function instead of other like what u said. Can you change it and give it a try ?

Comment: In my situation I cannot run 'use server' as I am in a client component where I use 'use client'. When I add 'use server' it give me an error saying 'use server' cannot be used in client components.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what thing makes `loading` is shown. Needing a state to control the status of loading. ex:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  async function handleFormData(formData: FormData) {
    setLoading(true)
    const result = await createUserFromForm(
      formData,
      clerkUserId as string,
      emailAddress as string
    )

    if (result) {
      await setUserDataAtClerk(
        clerkUserId as string,
        formData.get('firstName') as string,
        formData.get('lastName') as string
      )
      redirect('/dashboard')
    } else {
      console.error('User could not be created from form data')
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

And show the `Loading` component in the return part:

```
{loading && <Loading />}
```

Comment: Next JS doesn't need useState to show loading. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming

Comment: this is new to me. But I think the `loading` in your link only shows when loading the page for the first time.  It's don't show when the browser calls the API. To handle this I often use the state.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, but now my form validations are not triggering. 'required' html input fields are not triggering when I press form submit.

Comment: I just realised, the use of useState stops the whole handleFormData from triggering.